# Spring Boot: how to log httpStatus 500 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a AppErrorController that extends Boot's ErrorController in order to handle status500 errors. The example:

```
@Controller
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AppErrorController.class);
    private static final String ERROR = "error";
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "errorMessage";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
    public String error(Exception e, Model model) {
        LOGGER.error("500", e);
        model.addAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGE, "Internal server error");
        return ERROR;
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

I need the error to be logged. But the problem is that Exception e is always null. How to extract the actual error in order to log it?

---

ADDED

I have a GlobalExceptionHandler, but it never catches '500' errors

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);
    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're implementing this as a Controller and not via an `@ExceptionHandler` 

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason — it never works (see the additions above)

Comment: Are you getting the white page for the 500 error?

Comment: Why are you using `@Component` with `@ControllerAdvice`. Use only `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: jmw5598, no AppErrorController serves custom error page (return ERROR;)
And I don't care right now about what I get in the browser screen, but how to log this error on the server side

Comment: Are you positive nothing is catching or not-rethrowing the exceptions within the application? Have you tested your controller(s) with a `@WebMvcTest` slice test to verify the functionality?

Comment: Actually, I forgot to say, that the error is created in JSP layer. And I just was told, that JSP-layer errors do not get caught by @ControllerAdvice.

Comment: The information that the error comes from the JSP layer is crucial. Please edit the question and add it the the title and description. Otherwise, people may waste time reading through question, answer and all comments, and express their discontent through downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to catch exception from jsp layer is to define your own `error-page` and point it `location` to you controller. Then you can extract the actual cause and do with it whatever you like.

*web.xml*

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

*ErrorController*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorController.class);

    @RequestMapping
    public String ex(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        throwable.printStackTrace(); //print
        log.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable); // or log
        // or save to db
        return "error"; //and redirect to some user-friendly page
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I had to additionally implement Boot's ErrorController in order your solution to work.